# How to set IP segment and connection string with IPv6?

Tags: postgresql, connectivity, jdbc, ipv6

For this PostgreSQL configuration example:

https://repmgr.org/docs/4.4/quickstart-authentication.html

```
    local   replication   repmgr                              trust
    host    replication   repmgr      127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    replication   repmgr      192.168.1.0/24          trust

    local   repmgr        repmgr                              trust
    host    repmgr        repmgr      127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    repmgr        repmgr      192.168.1.0/24          trust
```

I have two questions.

## Question 1

This is how a netmask looks for IPv4: `192.168.1.0/24`.

How to do with an IPv6 IP address like `230b:c010:103:5858:a6a3:3:0:1`?

## Question 2

If use JDBC to connect to a PostgreSQL server, I can use a connection URL containing `192.168.1.11:5432`. How to do it with IPv6? Is it like `230b:c010:103:5858:a6a3:3:0:1:5432`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) says:

> An IPv6 address range might look like `::1/128` for a single host (in this case the IPv6 loopback address) or `fe80::7a31:c1ff:0000:0000/96` for a small network. `0.0.0.0/0` represents all IPv4 addresses, and `::0/0` represents all IPv6 addresses. To specify a single host, use a mask length of 32 for IPv4 or 128 for IPv6. In a network address, do not omit trailing zeroes.

**Answer 2:**

Like [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) says:

> - `host`
>
> The host name of the server. Defaults to `localhost`. To specify an IPv6 address your must enclose the `host` parameter with square brackets, for example:
>
> ```
> jdbc:postgresql://[::1]:5740/accounting
> ```

Comment: Very good answer! Thank you!